# Set base path in laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I have developed one simple application in laravel 4 using artisan commands.It's working fine using `php artisan serve` command line via port.But i wish to run by public folder like `localhost/myapp/public`.but my form are not posting in to any controller methods due to path

Form

```
{{ Form::open(array('post' => 'Controller@method')) }}
```

So how to set path for public so we can access methods by form request.thanks in advance.

--After form login---
 i going to redirect

```
return Redirect::intended('/user/home');
```

i have defined in usercontroller

```
  public function show()
    {
       return View::make('user.home');
    }
```

in route.php have

```
Route::resource('/user', 'UserController');
```

but i getting 404 Not Found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specify the controller and method in the Form open function you have to use `action`, not `post` as you have put in your question.

```
Form::open(array('action' => 'Controller@method'))
```

Hope that helps solve the issue.

Comment: thnks its works.But i after form submit i have redirected to home page of usercontroller by [return View::make('user.home');] i have usercontroller and view home page also i getting Not Found error

Comment: Glad the first bit is working. Not found error is usually because you don't have the route set up. Check the url where your getting the error has a entry in the routes.php file. Please update your question if that doesn't do the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Can you copy paste the exact error I might be wrong actually.

Comment: Your url is `/user/home` but do you have a route for it? This is not covered by `Route::resource('/user', 'UserController'); ` you would need to add `Route::get('user/home', 'UserController@home');` to your `routes.php` then make the home method in your controller. You could use the show method but this is really for a resource not for user home page. Does that make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79484/discussion-between-kishor-parmar-and-haakym).

Comment: I'm just loading my pc now. In the mean time please check if the route::get is above route::resource in routes.php otherwise it won't register it

Comment: thanks its problem was .htaccess file now working fine